# Hierarchical Columns in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, hierarchical-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljWcb.png)PLEASE SEE IMAGE. In the picture, rather than having 1, 2, ... as suffixes, I want them as a column title.

I would like to create a DataFrame such that I have a Hierchical structure that looks like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A B | A B | A B |

where 1, 2, and 3 are the main column titles, A and B are sub-column titles.

This is my code:
df_table = pd.DataFrame()

```
c=1

for event in results_full:

table = event.results(decimals=[3,5,3,5,2,2])

table = table.add_suffix('_'+str(c))

df_table = pd.concat([df_table, table], axis=1)

c += 1
```

Rather than having 1, 2, ..., as suffixes, I want to have them as higher-columns

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - perhaps you want a multi-index with the second level of the index being 'A/B/C/D'?

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it helps clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to represent the columns as 2 sub-columns.
However, if you set the information of each category (A and B) as a different dataframe you can unite them which might fit your needs.
Say the A info is saved as DF1 and B is DF2:
You can then use pd.concat([DF1, DF2], keys={"A": DF1, "B": DF2})
Hopes this helps in any way.

Comment: I have 19 dataframes so I don't think this is feasible. Thank you